# Data Query Webpart and Two Sharepoint lists

Tags: 2007

I have two SharePoint Lists: A & B. List A has a column where the user can add multilple references (displayed as hyperlinks) for each entry to entries in B

```
A:                            B:
... | RefB  | ...             Name | OtherColumns....
-----------------             -----------------------
... | B1    | ...             B1   |
... | B2,B3 | ...             B2   |
... | B1,B3 | ...             B3   |
```

Now I want to display all entries from list B that are referenced by an (specific) entry in A. I.e: I set the filter to [Entry 2] and the Web part displays all the stuff from entries B2 and B3. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

i am wondering if we could do an aggregate data sourse some how using a data view web part.  Here is a tutorial I found 
http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Performing_joins_between_SharePoint_lists.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It vaguely sounds like you want to group by the values in one column: have a read at this blog post to see if it sounds familiar to what you want to do:

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/04/15/sharepoint-group-by-a-column-with-multiple-values/